# Elastic search edgengram not searching properly

Tags: ruby-on-rails, elasticsearch

Shown here:
[Query hits](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uUFE8.png)

I search for "hey" and one of the retrieved records is "hello".

Another example is this:
[Query hits](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KMt1B.png)

Again, I search for "infrared" and a record with content: "This is a message at index: 1" shows up.

This is the settings for the index:

```
settings analysis: {
    filter: {
      edge_ngram_filter: {
        type: "edge_ngram",
        min_gram: "2",
        max_gram: "20",
      }
    },
    analyzer: {
      edge_ngram_analyzer: {
        type: "custom",
        tokenizer: "standard",
        filter: ["lowercase", "edge_ngram_filter"]
      }
    }
  } do
    mappings dynamic: true do
      indexes :content, type: :text, analyzer: "edge_ngram_analyzer"
      # indexes :chat_id, type: :long
    end
  end
```

Answer (score 0):

According to your index mapping tokens generated for `hey` will be

```
GET /_analyze

{
  "tokens": [
    {
      "token": "he",
      "start_offset": 0,
      "end_offset": 2,
      "type": "word",
      "position": 0
    },
    {
      "token": "hey",
      "start_offset": 0,
      "end_offset": 3,
      "type": "word",
      "position": 1
    }
  ]
}
```

Token generated for `hello` will be

```
GET /_analyze

{
  "tokens": [
    {
      "token": "he",
      "start_offset": 0,
      "end_offset": 2,
      "type": "word",
      "position": 0
    },
    {
      "token": "hel",
      "start_offset": 0,
      "end_offset": 3,
      "type": "word",
      "position": 1
    },
    {
      "token": "hell",
      "start_offset": 0,
      "end_offset": 4,
      "type": "word",
      "position": 2
    },
    {
      "token": "hello",
      "start_offset": 0,
      "end_offset": 5,
      "type": "word",
      "position": 3
    }
  ]
}
```

**Since both of the above have `he` token so if you search for `hey`, both the documents will match**

---

Modify your index mapping as

```
{
    "settings": {
        "analysis": {
            "analyzer": {
                "my_analyzer": {
                    "tokenizer": "my_tokenizer"
                }
            },
            "tokenizer": {
                "my_tokenizer": {
                    "type": "edge_ngram",
                    "min_gram": 3,            // note this
                    "max_gram": 10,
                    "token_chars": [
                        "letter",
                        "digit"
                    ]
                }
            }
        },
        "max_ngram_diff": 10
    },
    "mappings": {
        "properties": {
            "content": {
                "type": "text",
                "analyzer": "my_analyzer"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Now using analyze API

```
GET /_analyze

{
  "analyzer" : "my_analyzer",
  "text" : "hey"
}
```

Token will be

```
{
  "tokens": [
    {
      "token": "hey",
      "start_offset": 0,
      "end_offset": 3,
      "type": "word",
      "position": 0
    }
  ]
}
```

**Index Data:**

```
{
  "content": "hey"
}
{
  "content": "hello"
}
```

**Search Query:**

```
{
  "query":{
    "match":{
      "content":"hey"
    }
  }
}
```

**Search Result:**

```
"hits": [
      {
        "_index": "66754045",
        "_type": "_doc",
        "_id": "2",
        "_score": 0.8713851,
        "_source": {
          "content": "hey"
        }
      }
    ]
```

Comment: @torta did you get a chance to go through the answer, looking forward to get feedback from you :)